# IIS with laravel remove/hide index.php

Tags: laravel, iis

I have done configuration between iis and laravel project and it works fine but only when I include index.php to the link ex: localhost/projectname/index.php/homepage

note that iis point to the path of (projectname/public) folder

I did try iis url rewrite to import .htaccess  but it doesn't work, some suggestions to moving the files of the project to the public folder which does not make sense.

also, I did try renaming server.php to index.php and copying the .htacess file from public to root directory. not working

how can I remove index.php or hide it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use url rewrite. It will add index.php in url so that you don't need to add it when enter url in browser.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="Rewriter" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\\.php|images|css|js|favicon\\.ico)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```